# Как обеспечить работу кода во всех браузерах (window.location.href)?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы такой код javascript работал во всех браузерах (сейчас работает только вв IE):

```
window.location.href ="/admin/?page=order&amp;admitem=add_model&amp;action=saveorder&amp;banid=<?=GetParam('banid')?>&amp;par_data="+par_data;
```

В остальных браузерах происходит переход на страницу, но не передаются параметры.

Comment: Покажите весь код.

Comment: Что-то у вас понамешано ту - и JS, и PHP... Да, код не помешало бы увидеть побольше

Answer (score 1):

Всё, проблема решилась - вместо &amp; надо было писать &